# Where can I find tower information

Tags: api, geolocation, services

I want to find geolocation with GSM Cell information. I need tower information to find locations and calculate triangulation. I tried OpenCellID service but I think it's not up to date. I can't find the cell towers near me on the OpenCellID map.

Can anybody suggest an up to date free or paid service? I can also accept any other solutions?

Comment: have you tried http://wireless.fcc.gov/antenna/index.htm?job=uls_transaction&page=weekly

Comment: Nope. It doesn't even come up to me with my searches. I'm checking it out immediately

Comment: What part of the world? What's this device you have? What data is it getting to you? Has anything changed since you posted this? Do you care anymore or can we delete this?

Comment: I mostly need Europe and West Asia continents. I'm getting cell ID's from the GPS device. Nothing has changed yet. Yes I still care this topic.

Comment: You might have better luck re-asking this in the [OpenData SE](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few sites you may want to check out:

- http://www.cellreception.com/towers/
- http://opensignal.com/
- http://www.towerco.com/simplicityfound/
- https://location.services.mozilla.com/downloads